# Git suppressing output of other print statements when used via subprocess.call

Tags: python, git, subprocess

Within a script, I am making a git commit

```
 def test():
   ...:     subprocess.call(['git','--no-pager','commit','-m',"no pager test"])
   ...:     print "hello"
```

I added the no pager option after reading about it online, but it doesn't help. On running test() you can see that "hello" won't be printed.

Comment: Git doesn't suppress *anything*. It just doesn't return for some reason, but `subprocess.call()` waits for it to complete. If you were to kill the waiting child process the `print` would be executed.

Comment: You may want to look at [GitPython](https://gitorious.org/git-python) instead of mucking about with subprocesses yourself.

Comment: I am using `git version 1.8.3.2` and `Python 2.7.5` and it works for me... In fact, it works without the `--no-pager` option as well. Can you tell the python and git versions you have?

Comment: @mu無 git version 1.9.1, Python 2.7.6